# ansible docker_image invalid reference format

Tags: docker, ansible

Me need take value from group vars and download some image from dockerhub, but value put incorrectly.

My playbook:

```
hosts: all

tasks:
  name: download image
  docker_image:
  name: 
   - "{{image}}"
  source: pull
```

My group_vars

```
 image:
  nginx
  ubuntu
```

And error message:

```
fatal: [linux1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error pulling image ['((image))']:latest - 400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=%5B%27%28%28image%29%29%27%5D: Bad Request (\"invalid reference format\")"}
```

I tried different syntax variant and update my app

I understand this problem. docker_image just requires specifying tags

Comment: As an addition to larsk's answer below, you might want to read [the relevant parameter description in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html#parameter-name) as well as a [5 minutes basic tutorial on yaml syntax](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)

Comment: => https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/ab48aeddabc85fbfb576386be112c334

Comment: What's "items"?
                                       name: "{{ item }}"

Comment: And for what here "loop"?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Comment: Thanks! Its really interesting, but its too not work for me.

Comment: ["it's not working" is not an accurate description of your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). And some more advice for a quality time on SO: 1) don't use comments as a chat, they're not made for that 2) read documentations and basic tutorials **before** you ask your question. 3) read [ask] paying a particular attention to the [mre] section. 4) be aware of the [efforts exepted from stackoverflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9401096). Good luck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` argument to the `docker_image` module should be a string, not a list:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: download image
      docker_image:
        name: "{{image}}"
        source: pull
```